# Lambda Authorizer Policy not restricting access to Api Gateway proxy resource

Tags: aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi, lambda-authorizer

I have a Lambda authorizer (python) that returns a resource-based policy similar to the following:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    resource = "*"
    headerValue = _get_header_value(event, 'my-header')
    if headerValue == 'a':
        resource = "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*/*/GET/a"
    return {
        "principalId": f"somebody",
        "policyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Resource": f"{resource}"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Basically, this authorizer will return an unrestricted api resource policy by default, using `*`.  However, if a specific header value is passed, the policy will restrict access to only allow `GET /a`.

On the ApiGateway side of things, the only resource I have is `ANY /{proxy+}` which [proxies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html) into a .NET Core WebApi using [APIGatewayProxyFunction](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer). Inside the APIGatewayProxyFunction/WebApi, I have a number of Controllers and routes available, including `GET /a`.  After all this is deploying into AWS, I can construct an http request using `my-header` with value `a`.  I'm expecting this request to only provide access to `GET /a`, and return a 403 in all other cases.  Instead, it provides access to everything in the api, similar to the star policy.

Is this the expected behavior when using a Lambda Authorizer in front of a proxy resource?  It seems to really only enforce `Allow *` or `Deny *`.  Thank you.

*Note - When using the same authorizer against an Api Gateway where all the resources defined inside it (instead of inside .NET Controllers by proxy), the expected behavior does appear to happen - the http request with `my-header` set to 'a' will grant access to `GET /a`, but return 403 otherwise.*